# Rails Controller not picking up matching models and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

So my Rails controller isn't working (properly) for some reason.

I first noticed something funny when I opened the controller file for the first time.

[image: Vim Sytax Highlighting Pr]

Compare this to normal syntax highlighting. (Also notice the overly long name)

[image: Normal Syntax Highlighting]

This was the error I got when I tried to create a link in one of my views.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_voyage_at_port_log_entries_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb1c5921a98>:0x007fb1c81a32a0>):
```

Here's proof that I inserted this in my routes.

```
resources :voyage_at_port_log_entries
```

I do have it working by creating manual routes, but that is a little awkward, and I may forsee problems later. Why might ActionView not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DUH! Routes are created for the singular version.

So...

```
new_voyage_at_port_log_entry_path
```

works!

BUT...syntax highlighting is still off...
Hmmm...not important but weird...probably has a different pluralization engine?

Comment: The routes created by `resources` use both singular and plural names, as appropriate to the context.  If you're operating on a collection (the index path, for example), it'll use a plural name.  If you're operating on a single item (show, update, etc.), it'll use a singular name.  Syntax highlighting is your editor's responsibility and has nothing to do with Ruby, Rails, or the pluralization system.